# Polymorphic relationship with multikey primary key -> automatic mapping attibute not found

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5.8

I am setting up a parent->n-children model relationship (multi table) for a medical clinic and trying to automatically map the parent data. I am getting an `array_key_exists(): The first argument should be either a string or an integer` error.

I am following along with this tutorial: https://design-patterns12.blogspot.com/2018/01/laravel-model-inheritance-through.html

The DB relationship is:
Episode (PK'['audit', 'episode', 'mrn']')
Abstract Ward
One of five different types of `Ward`. Each of these has ~100 fields that are independent of each other and the Episode parent.

```php
class Episode extends Model
{
    use HasCompositePrimaryKey;

    protected $table = 'episodes';
    protected $primaryKey = ['audit', 'episode', 'mrn'];
    public $incrementing = false;
    protected $fillable = ['audit', 'episode', 'mrn'];
    protected $ward_fields = [];
    public $timestamps = false;

    public function audit()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo($this->audit(), 'id');
    }

    public function ward()
    {
        return $this->morphTo();
    }

    public function __get($name) {
        $ret = parent::__get($name);

        if ($ret === null) {

            if (isset($this->ward_fields[$name])) {
                $ret = $this->ward_fields[$name];
            } else if (array_key_exists('ward', $this->getRelations())) {
                $ret = $this->ward->{$name};
            }
        }

        return $ret;
    }

    public function __toString() {
        return $this->audit . ' ' . $this->episode . ' ' . $this->mrn;
    }
}
```

Abstract Class

```php
<?php

namespace App;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

abstract class Ward extends Episode
{
    public $timestamps = false;
    protected $episode_fields = [];

    public function parent_episode()
    {
        return $this->morphOne(Episode::class, 'ward');
    }

    public function __get($name)
    {
        $ret = parent::__get($name);

        if ($ret === null) {
            if (isset($this->episode_fields[$name])) {
                $ret = $this->episode_fields[$name];
            } else if ($this->parent_episode()->count() > 0) {
                $ret = $this->episode->{$name};
            }
        }

        return $ret;
    }

    public function __set($key, $value)
    {
        if (!Schema::hasColumn($this->getTable(), $key)) {
            $this->episode_fields[$key] = $value;
        } else {
            parent::__set($key, $value);
        }
    }

    public function __unset($key)
    {
        if (!Schema::hasColumn($this->getTable(), $key)) {
            unset($this->episode_fields[$key]);
        } else {
            parent::__unset($key);
        }
    }

    public function __isset($key)
    {
        if (!Schema::hasColumn($this->getTable(), $key)) {
            return isset($this->episode_fields[$key]);
        } else {
            return parent::__isset($key);
        }
    }

    public function save(array $options = array())
    {
        $ret = parent::save($options);

        if ($ret) {
            $episode = $this->episode;


            if ($episode == null) {
                $episode = new Episode;
            }

            foreach ($this->episode_fields as $key => $value) {
                $episode->{$key} = $value;
            }

            $episode->save();

            $this->parent_episode()->save($episode);
        }

        return $ret;
    }

    public function delete()
    {
        $ret = false;

        if ($this->episode->delete()) {
            $ret = parent::delete();
        }

        return $ret;
    }

}
```

Example.test `Rehabilitation` ward

```php
namespace App\Ward;
use App\Ward;

class Rehabilitation extends Ward
{
    protected $table = 'rehabilitations';
    protected $with = ['episodes'];
    protected $fillable = ['audit', 'episode', 'mrn'];
    public $timestamps = false;
}
```

this all seems to go well until I run the seed and stumble at the save() method

```
 ErrorException  : array_key_exists(): The first argument should be either a string or an integer

  at /Users/doug/Code/Snap/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Concerns/HasAttributes.php:317
    313| 
    314|         // If the attribute exists in the attribute array or has a "get" mutator we will
    315|         // get the attribute's value. Otherwise, we will proceed as if the developers
    316|         // are asking for a relationship's value. This covers both types of values.
  > 317|         if (array_key_exists($key, $this->attributes) ||
    318|             $this->hasGetMutator($key)) {
    319|             return $this->getAttributeValue($key);
    320|         }
    321| 

  Exception trace:

  1   array_key_exists([])
      /Users/doug/Code/Snap/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Concerns/HasAttributes.php:317

  2   Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model::getAttribute()
      /Users/doug/Code/Snap/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Relations/HasOneOrMany.php:376

  3   Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasOneOrMany::getParentKey()
      /Users/doug/Code/Snap/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Relations/HasOneOrMany.php:70

  4   Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasOneOrMany::addConstraints()
      /Users/doug/Code/Snap/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Relations/MorphOneOrMany.php:51

  5   Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\MorphOneOrMany::addConstraints()
      /Users/doug/Code/Snap/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Relations/Relation.php:71

  6   Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\Relation::__construct(Object(Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder), Object(App\Ward\Rehabilitation))
      /Users/doug/Code/Snap/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Relations/HasOneOrMany.php:46

  7   Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasOneOrMany::__construct(Object(Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder), Object(App\Ward\Rehabilitation), "episodes.ward_id")
      /Users/doug/Code/Snap/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Relations/MorphOneOrMany.php:40

  8   Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\MorphOneOrMany::__construct(Object(Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder), Object(App\Ward\Rehabilitation), "episodes.ward_type", "episodes.ward_id")
      /Users/doug/Code/Snap/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Concerns/HasRelationships.php:158

  9   Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model::newMorphOne(Object(Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder), Object(App\Ward\Rehabilitation), "episodes.ward_type", "episodes.ward_id")
      /Users/doug/Code/Snap/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Concerns/HasRelationships.php:143

  10  Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model::morphOne("App\Episode", "ward")
      /Users/doug/Code/Snap/app/Ward.php:14

  11  App\Ward::parent_episode()
      /Users/doug/Code/Snap/app/Ward.php:77

  12  App\Ward::save()
      /Users/doug/Code/Snap/database/seeds/Ward/RehabilitationTableSeeder.php:31

  13  RehabilitationTableSeeder::run()
      /Users/doug/Code/Snap/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/BoundMethod.php:32

  14  call_user_func_array([])
      /Users/doug/Code/Snap/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/BoundMethod.php:32

  15  Illuminate\Container\BoundMethod::Illuminate\Container\{closure}()
      /Users/doug/Code/Snap/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/BoundMethod.php:90

  16  Illuminate\Container\BoundMethod::callBoundMethod(Object(Illuminate\Foundation\Application), Object(Closure))
      /Users/doug/Code/Snap/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/BoundMethod.php:34

  17  Illuminate\Container\BoundMethod::call(Object(Illuminate\Foundation\Application), [])
      /Users/doug/Code/Snap/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php:576

  18  Illuminate\Container\Container::call()
      /Users/doug/Code/Snap/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Seeder.php:122

  19  Illuminate\Database\Seeder::__invoke()
      /Users/doug/Code/Snap/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Seeder.php:42

  20  Illuminate\Database\Seeder::call("RehabilitationTableSeeder")
      /Users/doug/Code/Snap/database/seeds/DatabaseSeeder.php:18

  21  DatabaseSeeder::run()
      /Users/doug/Code/Snap/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/BoundMethod.php:32
```

I was expecting that the success the person in the tutorial I was following could be replicated.

I can see a couple of issues in the code that I do not quite understand:
In the `Ward` class, The `save()` method has a `$this->episode` magic variable that I am not sure how it gets set. It also returns an integer while I would have expected that it returns an (`Episode`) object.

Can someone help shed some light on this?

Comment: Still working on this and I think I have more info now. The stack trace and further debugging suggests to me that morph fields cant handle composite fields. The error is that the 'get primary key' function is using `array_key_exists` while being passed an array (of the primary key) as the first parameter. Is it possible to override this for this particular case using a trait?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The final answer on this is that Eloquent can support multi key primary keys, Laravell can not. Thats it really.